# How to create a Redux store using combineReducers without initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following Redux store:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

export function configureStore() {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer);

  return store;
};

const store = configureStore()
export default store;
```

This is the `rootReducer` created with `combineReducers`:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import application from '../features/application/reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  application,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

And this is the creation of the provider:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './app/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
Error: The slice reducer for key "application" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.
```

I checked [this documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers), and I can't find a solution to my problem.

**EDIT**

I see that the problem might be related to webpack, but I have no idea of this:

This is the code for `application` reducer:

```
import { ActionInterface } from '../generals';
import {
  FETCH_APPLICATION_COMPOSITE_SUCCESS,
  SET_CURRENT_APPLICATION_COMPONENT
} from './actions';

const INIT_STATE = {
  applicationComposite: null,
  currentApplicationComponent: null
}

export default (state=INIT_STATE, action: ActionInterface) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_APPLICATION_COMPOSITE_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        //@ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        applicationComposite: action.payload.applicationComposite
      }
    }
    case SET_CURRENT_APPLICATION_COMPONENT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        //@ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        currentApplicationComponent: action.payload.applicationComponent
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be willing to show your code for the `application` reducer?

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt I added the code you request. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Try to add `default: return INIT_STATE;` to your `application` reducer at the end of the `switch`.

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt, that was it!!! thank you so much. It was a silly mistake

Comment: Shouldn't that be `default: return state;`? @PeterLehnhardt

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt oh yea, I actually noticed about it and made it `default: return {...state}`

Comment: For change detection and immutability I think you want just `state`, not a new object with the same properties. It shouldn't change the object at all if it's passed an action it doesn't recognize. @HuLuViCa

Comment: @IanMercer Yeah, you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add default return to your reducer

```
import { ActionInterface } from '../generals';
import {
  FETCH_APPLICATION_COMPOSITE_SUCCESS,
  SET_CURRENT_APPLICATION_COMPONENT
} from './actions';

const INIT_STATE = {
  applicationComposite: null,
  currentApplicationComponent: null
}

export default (state=INIT_STATE, action: ActionInterface) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_APPLICATION_COMPOSITE_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        //@ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        applicationComposite: action.payload.applicationComposite
      }
    }
    case SET_CURRENT_APPLICATION_COMPONENT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        //@ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        currentApplicationComponent: action.payload.applicationComponent
      }
    }
    default: return state;
  }
}
```